# Git Push and Commit From Replit

Tags: python, github, replit

So I've recently found out that I could connect my repositories from GitHub to replit. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to push and commit my code from replit onto my repository.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/72625554/9935654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has been answered in replit tutorials and replit forums. [link](https://replit.com/talk/ask/SOLVED-Is-it-possible-to-use-git/12937) to the forum question, [link](https://replit.com/talk/learn/Replit-Git-Tutorial/23331) to the official tutorial

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).